# Network Discovery of multiple devices using snmpget on net-snmp

Tags: networking, snmp, net-snmp

I'm sending a request to the broadcast address of the network using snmpget to get the status of all the devices connected to the network

```
snmpget -v 2c -c public 255.255.255.255 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0
```

and this OID gives me the information of my system

```
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: Linux harry-aspire-e5-572g 4.15.0-39-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 24 17:09:54 UTC 2018 x86_64
```

Now, the other device's information connected to the network doesn't show up using snmpget broadcast request but the request is logged on that device's system logs of receiving the snmpget request.

I don't wish to use a third party tool like nmap.

Comment: What is the SNMP Agent in use? Can you configure it to respond to broadcast requests? There's not enough information here to answer.

Comment: I'm using net-snmp for the purpose and yes I've enabled the flag for sending broadcast request

Comment: When I send the broadcast request on the network, from my snmp-manager, I get the details of only one device connected to the network on the terminal, while there are other devices on the network whose information I don't get via snmpget broadcast request but on checking the log files of the other devices, these devices were pinged by the snmp-manager for the discovery purpose